# calling webservice POST method from HTML page using ajax?500 internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

my html page code is this

```
   function Save_Click() {


      if (validate() == true)
       {
           var dr = {};

         dr.phoneNo = phoneNo;
          dr.mobileNo = mobileNo;
          dr.Adress = Adress;
          dr.dob = dob;
         var Record = JSON.stringify(dr);



          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",

              url: "doctorRecord.asmx/Save_Update_Doctor",

              data: Record,
              contentType: "application/json",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {

                  alert("successfully saved");

              },
              error: function (result) {
                  //alert("Error login");

              }
          });


      }


  };
```

my webservice.asmx code is

```
    [WebMethod]
    public  object  Save_Update_Doctor(Doctor_Business.Model.Doctor info)
    {


  //code here
   return "something"
    }
```

my JSON Data POST is

```
  "{"phoneNo":"jsmith","mobileNo":"AC101","Adress":"2817 S 49th\nApt 314\nSan Jose, CA 95101","dob":"24-01-2016"}"
```

the error is

> ```
>   Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/Save_Update_Doctor'.
> ```
>
> http://localhost:62730/Forms/Theme/doctorRecord.asmx/Save_Update_Doctor
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

I TESTED THE WEBSERVICE USING TEST MODE BUT RUN SUCESSFULL BUT WHEN I TRIED TO CALL FROM HTML page any WEB METHOD IS **.cs** Class return 403 request forbiddenn and webservice always return internal server 500

what is wrong i have this web.config file what changes or code should i add kindly check the above code and tell?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

working web service url

```
 localhost:62730/Forms/Theme/doctorRecord.asmx?op=Save_Update_Doctor
```

and url to be used is this

```
  localhost:62730/Forms/Theme/doctorRecord.asmx/Save_Update_Doctor
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following configuration element in web.config inside `<system.web>`

```
 <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
```

**Update**

One more important thing. In order for the asmx script to be accessible from the client side, we need to include

```
[ScriptService]
```

Comment: Unrecognized configuration section webServices.  `Line 12:   <webServices>`

Comment: still `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:62730/Forms/Theme/doctorRecord.asmx/Save_Update_Doctor"`

Comment: Have you added inside <system.web>?

Comment: Are you able to hit the Save_Update_Doctor method in debug mode

Comment: yes hitting success actually what will be json format infact it is creating peoblem

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/json-hijacking-and-how-asp-net-ajax-1-0-mitigates-these-attacks

Comment: `contentType: "application/json"`, but  work  `contentType: "application/text"`, why i need first one

Comment: The Content-Type header field is used to specify the nature of the data in the body

Comment: good work comment is my 50% answer and 50% how to call a class.cs web method from html as i am calling webservice is sucessful and same replacing class.cs name not works

Comment: working url is this `(doctorRecord.asmx?op=Save_Update_Doctor)` but this is to be used `(doctorRecord.cs/Save_Update_Doctor)`

Comment: .cs extensions is not required

Comment: Just had a situation where my test server (IIS/10) had no issues with this, then the deployed server (IIS/8.5) barfed on my web service using POST. I guess that's a machine.config difference or something they changed. Whatever, the web.config change suggested here fixed it immediately. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't stringify your data in the ajax call, since jQuery does it for you. Here, you send a string to the server, not a json object.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "doctorRecord.asmx/Save_Update_Doctor",
  data: Record,
  success: function(data) {
    alert("successfully saved");
  },
  error: function(result) {
    //alert("Error login");
  }
});
```

Also, your webservice seems strange. You method should receive an object of Class XX with properties phoneNo, mobileNo, etc.

```
public class Infos
{
    public string phoneNo = {get; set; };
    public string mobileNo = {get; set; };
    // ...
}

[WebMethod]
public  string  Save_Update_Doctor(Infos infos)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: tried already but not resolved same error i think some kind of permission code must be added in web.config but any how this not work

Comment: working url  id this `(http://localhost:62730/Forms/Theme/doctorRecord.asmx?op=Save_Update_Doctor )`  but this is to be used  `(http://localhost:62730/Forms/Theme/doctorRecord.asmx/Save_Update_Doctor)`

Comment: let me check i am implementing that